# How to stop Tab Bar Item images' background width changing when tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, uitabbaritem

When I click on tab bar item images their background (or whatever it is) width is increased. As you can see in the screenshot below image size is fixed but background width increases after I tap on any of them.

Does anyone know how to stop it happening?

Following is the code in my UITabBarController View

```
    for tabBarItem in (self.tabBar.items)!{
        tabBarItem.title = ""
        tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6.0, 0.0, -6.0, 0.0)

        let viewTabBar = tabBarItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
        let imgView = viewTabBar?.subviews[0] as? UIImageView

        imgView?.frame.size.height = 32
        imgView?.frame.size.width = 32

        imgView?.clipsToBounds = true
        imgView?.backgroundColor = .red
    }
```

[image: Tabbar item images before and after click]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding that code inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, Then instead of setting the imageView size and width just add the image as an image to the `tabBarItem`.

I don't know what name of the tab images you used are but for an example let's call the first image inside xcassests `homeIcon`, the second image `middleIcon` and the last image `settingsIcon`

This is the way I would subclass my TabBarController using those images and the other code to center the image without an image title inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let homeVC = HomeController()
        let navVCHome = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC)
        navVCHome.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "homeIcon"), tag: 0)

        let middleVC = MiddleController()
        let navVCMiddle = UINavigationController(rootViewController: middleVC)
        navVCMiddle.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "middleIcon"), tag: 1)

        let settingsVC = SettingsController()
        let navVCSettings = UINavigationController(rootViewController: settingsVC)
        navVCSettings.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "settingsIcon"), tag: 2)

        viewControllers = [navVCHome, navVCMiddle, navVCSettings]
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        for tabBarItem in tabBar.items ?? [] {

             tabBarItem.title = ""
             tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6.0, left: 0.0, bottom: -6.0, right: 0.0 )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. My actual issue is badge which doesn't sit on the top right  corner of these icons because there is some width issue with these icons and I can't figure out why it's happening. None of the methods I've tried so far works.

Comment: If it’s a badge issue you need to change the title or include it in the question. I didn’t see anything about a badge in either place

Comment: Badge is suppose to be placed where it should be placed and it will be placed correctly if icons are placed correctly otherwise we will end up in repositioning badge all the time.

Answer (score 0):

It should have been easy to spot by logical analysis alas! neither could I or anyone else figured it out.

There was a code which was changing the size of selected tab bar item image. I removed this code and it's working fine. As I wrote it my comment above if image sizes are correctly set then badge always position itself correctly and there is no need to reposition badges.